# Sprite Kit: Count of SKSpriteNodes on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skspritenode

This seems like a really easy question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.  I am making a game using Sprite Kit, and I would like to get the count of how many SKNodes I currently have on the screen.  I can see the count on the bottom right corner in my debugging information, but I'm not sure how to access it as an integer I can use to program with.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple docs say, "An SKScene object represents a scene of content in Sprite Kit. A scene is the root node in a tree of Sprite Kit nodes..."

So, use the following statement in your SKScene class, see if it outputs the correct number.

```
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[self.children count]);
```

Comment: Scene's node count counts only nodes, which are visible to the user, so it may not be equal to `self.children.count`. So that's not exactly what OP asks for

Comment: True, for example...if one were to be using tmx maps, the tmx tiles would be visible in the SKScene showsNodeCount, and not in [self.children count]. However, this doesn't apply to @MSU_Bulldog, or does it?

Comment: It's worth noting that self.children only returns the immediate siblings of the scene and does not recursively count any nodes that might be parented to the children.